# How to check a expire date every day

Tags: server, webserver, cloud

For example: Someone creates an ad to be aired for 1 month, how do I check when that date comes. I was thinking in a program that runs every day to check every row in a database and check the expiration date and do what it should do. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I was looking for is [*cron jobs*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron)